How to solve the error read econnreset error in vscode
I want to develop a node js application
In that i am getting this error regularly
Please help me
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "pass@",
  database: "mydb",
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("Connected");
});

app.get("/r", (req, res) => {
  const q = `select * from fbads`;
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err.code);
    } else {
      return res.send(data);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000);


it shows results only 10 seconds after it shows error
Thank you...
I have tried it
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
after that run
npm install -g @angular/cli
but not working

What is the connection between the code you attached to npm config set registry?
And what is the connection to React/Angular?
What did you expect your code to do and what doesn't it do?
